# Interaction between jquery,MySQL and PHP to retrieve the result

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have two file, `test.html` & `test.php`. I would like to display the result of an SQL query via jQuery AJAX.

`test.php` outputs proper JSON, but I'm not able fetch the same on clicking upon the button "Fetch Data".  Is it wrong way of using AJAX?

Once fetching the data in `test.html`, how do I access the contents?

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $ajax({
                url:'test.php',
                type:'get',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                console.log(data['success']);
                console.log(data.success);           
                }
    });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button>Fetch Data</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbname="test";
    $dbpass="root";
    $dbserver="localhost";
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    $con = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
    // Create a Query
    $sql_query = "SELECT ID, UserName, Status FROM user_details1";
    // Execute query
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
    $jsonArray = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $jsonArrayItem = array();
        $jsonArrayItem["ID"] = $row["ID"];
        $jsonArrayItem["UserName"] = $row["UserName"];
        $jsonArrayItem["Status"] = $row["Status"];
        array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
    //echo '<option value='. $row['id'] . '>'. $row['login'] . '</option>';
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    $tableData = array(
            "data" => $jsonArray
        );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($tableData,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    die();
  ?>
```

How do I display/access/print the fetched result contents (AJAX section)?

Comment: missed a dot between $ and ajax `$ajax({...`. It should be `$.ajax({...`

Comment: In the future, you should debug these types of problems using developer tools for your browser like firebug.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer I don't believe there's an extra `}` anywhere. @Kosmos is correct in that it must be `$.ajax` and not `$ajax`.

Comment: @TylerRoper Both of you are correct.

Comment: Sorry, that's avery silly mistake from myside. And there's no extra }. I could alert now but i don't see any data fetched from test.php .

Comment: There is no `success` property in the JSON data you are echoing.  Try to `console.log(data);` to see what you *actually* have.   Note that `alert()` is not a good debugging tool.

Comment: Also, if you are just learning, then you may want to know that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (and possibly even ***removed***) in PHP.  You should be learning to use `mysqli_*` (or PDO) functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like this

```
var dataToSend = "My Data";

$(button).on("click",function(event){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: { pDataToSend: dataToSend }
    }).done(function( data ) {
      $('.results').empty();
      $('.results').append(data);
    });
});
```

And make a div like this

```
<div class="results></div>
```

In your PHP file you can read the POST using this code.

```
$foo = $_POST['pDataToSend'];
```

Also, your test.php file is all over the place. Use a PDO like this

```
//connect and setup database example
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=second;port=8889","root","root");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo 'Could not connect to the database.105';
  exit();
}

//select,insert,delete, update from database example
try{
  $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
  $results->bindParam(1,$var);
  $results->bindParam(2,$var2);
  $results->execute();
  $hold = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Data could not be retrieved from the database.";
  exit();
}
```